# I have a DataFrame grouped by two columns, and I want to apply a style function to the DataFrame

Tags: python

I have a DataFrame grouped by two columns, and I want to apply a style function to the DataFrame. But when I apply the style function, my DataFrame is not grouped by the two columns any more.

#### Without applying style

```py
# Concatenate the dataframes with labels
combined_df = pd.concat(list_pd_p_value, keys=labels)

# Reset the index of the combined dataframe
combined_df = combined_df.reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={'level_0': 'label'})

combined_df = pd.concat([
    combined_df.groupby(['label','app_name'], group_keys=False)['p_value']
        .apply(lambda x: x.tolist()[0])
        .to_frame(name='p_value'),
    combined_df.groupby(['label','app_name'], group_keys=False)['OddsRatio']
        .apply(lambda x: x.tolist()[0])
        .to_frame(name='OddsRatio'),
    combined_df.groupby(['label','app_name'], group_keys=False)['result']
        .apply(lambda x: x.tolist()[0])
        .to_frame(name='result')
], axis=1)

combined_df
```

Output with groupby but not style:

[image: df without style with groupby]

#### After applying style

```py
combined_df = combined_df.reset_index()

styled_df = combined_df.style.format({'p_value': '{:.2f}'}, precision=1)

# Apply the color_cell function to the 'p_value' column of the DataFrame
styled_df = styled_df.apply(color_cell, subset='result')

# Set CSS styles to hide the index column
css = [{'selector': '.row_heading, .blank', 'props': 'display: none;'}]
styled_df.set_table_styles(css)

# Display the styled DataFrame
display(styled_df) 


def color_cell(cell):
    """
    Applies background color to cells based on their values.

    Parameters:
        cell (pandas.core.series.Series): A pandas Series representing a cell.

    Returns:
        list: A list of CSS styles corresponding to each cell value.

    Examples:
        >>> color_cell(pd.Series(['Regression', 'Improvement', 'WP']))
        ['background-color: #EF4B4B', 'background-color: #DDFFBB', 'background-color: #F5B971']
    """
    styles = []
    for value in cell:
        if value == 'Regression':
            styles.append('background-color: #EF4B4B')
        elif value == 'Improvement':
            styles.append('background-color: #DDFFBB')
        elif value == 'WP':
            styles.append('background-color: #F5B971')
        else:
            styles.append('')
    return styles
```

Output with style but not groupby:

[image: df with style but not groupby]

How can I style the DataFrame while keeping it grouped by the two columns?